# Dynamically set value for <spring:url/>

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc

How do I dynamically set a value for the `<spring:url/>` tag using javascript.

Ex:

```
<spring:url value="/page1/createEdit" var="url"/>
```

I need to change the value to have some parameter dynamically. like so

```
 <spring:url value="/page1/createEdit?id=225" var =url/>
```

I know I can do this for a normal `<a>` tag. But how do I do it for the spring:url.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will execute at client side in browser. In browser you will have generated html not `spring:url`. You will have html anchor tag `<a href="/page1/createEdit"/>`

In JS you can lookup the anchor tag and change the href value.